# Swift.h file not found CocoaPods 1.5.3

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, cocoapods

I am trying to use `cocoapods` swift Static Libraries. But those frameworks which include obj-c and swift file had the error:

> *-Swift.h file not found*

My configuration is:

- Pod Version 1.5.3
- s.static_framework = true (.podspec)
- use_modular_headers! was added in .pod
- use_frameworks! was removed in .pod
- Objective-C generics set to YES in Build Phases.

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Try clean project -> quiting xcode -> cleaning derived data -> Restart xcode...

Comment: It doesn't help.

Answer (score 0):

```
#use_frameworks! was removed in .pod
```

Please remove # and install pod again 
like this

```
#use_frameworks! was removed in
```